# Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL' - Firebase upload photo tutorial

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm a total neeb to programming but trying to follow this YouTube tutorial on how to use Firebase and build an app to upload images. It's going great but I'm stuck on the fact that downloadURL no longer is a property of storage metadata. I know it's been answered before how to get around this BUT seeing as I'm new I'm having a hard time updating the code I'm using to this. Anyone able to help me?

Getting:

```
Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'" at self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absolutestring
```

```
func save(){
    //1. create a new database reference
    let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("photoPosts").childByAutoId()
    let newPostKey = newPostRef.key!

    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.6) {
        //2. create a new storage reference
        let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
        let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostKey)

        //3. save the image to storage 1st
        newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler:
            { (snapshot) in

                //4. save the post caption & download URL
                self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absolutestring
                let newPostDictionary = [
                    "imageDownloadURL" : self.imageDownloadURL,
                    "caption" : self.caption
                ]
                newPostRef.setValue(newPostDictionary)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial you're following is very old.  The APIs have changed.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know :/ Do you happen to know another good, easy to follow along-YouTube tutorial for uploading images in a "feed" type of manner? Swift Xcode :)